# Function call is being stacked up

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I've got a bootstrap modal which shows a confirmation message. If the 'accept' button is clicked then a function is being called with an id, if 'cancel' or 'close' buttons are clicked then the modal closes. The issue is that when the modal is displayed, if I clicked on cancel, and then open the modal again and this time I click on 'accept', the function is being called twice, once for the time I clicked on cancel and once for the time I clicked on 'accept'. How can I prevent this?

```
$(document).ready(initItems)


function initItems() {
    $('.delete-item').on('click', initItemDeletion)
}

function initItemDeletion() {
    const itemId = $(this).data('item-id')
    $('h5.modal-title').text('Confirmation')
    $('div.modal-content div.modal-body').text('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')
    $('div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-primary').text('Yes, Delete It!')
    $('#main-modal').modal()
    $('div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-primary').click(() => {
        deleteItem(itemId)
        $('#main-modal').modal('hide')   
    })
    return 

}

function deleteItem(itemId) {
    console.log('deleting item...' + itemId)

}
```

Again:

1. click on link: modal is shown but I click on cancel.
   Console prints: nothing
2. click on link: modal is shown but I click on accept.
   Console prints:
   deleting item... 2
   deleting item... 9

where item 2 was the row of the item I clicked on the first time, and 9 is the current row I'm clicking on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that every time you open new modal, you bind to `div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-primary` button, so when you close the modal, it is still there, and when you open new one, you bind again on top of that.

Bind to namespaced click event and unbind it just before, so you always have just one handler:

```
$('div.modal-footer button.btn.btn-primary').off('click.close').on('click.close', function () {
    deleteItem(itemId)
    $('#main-modal').modal('hide')   
})
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/219529/

https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: your fiddle is not working either, open up Developer Tools and then Console, you will see that the same issue is happening. You click on Delete 1 and then close it, the console shows nothing, but click then on Delete 3 and the on the confirmation message and you will see the console printing deleting item 1 and deleting item 2

Comment: You're right, I was testing it wrong way, give me a sec :]

Comment: Ah finally I understand your issue!

Comment: Done, even simpler - just unbind right before binding.

Comment: Yay! Now it's working, thanks a lot for taking the time on helping me. Would you mind elaborate your answer as why this was happening so I can understand better your solution? Thanks again

Comment: Done, hope it helps